# Circle Boarder Not Showing In IE11

Tags: css, border, geometry, internet-explorer-11

I have a problem with my site that the circle image border does noes not display correctly in IE11 (the boarder remains square although the image is a circle) but is fine in Chrome, Safari & Firefox. 
Here's the site http://www.mvclatworthy.co.uk/

Comment: Would be great if you post your HTML and CSS

Comment: Hi,  i'm not sure which part of the css this covers as it was built using Wordpress / Visual Composer.

Comment: Well in that case it is very hard for us to help you without knowing the code

Comment: Would firebug not show this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Interesting issue with IE11, if there is no actual border then it will not clip the image, try adding

```
border: 1px solid #f4524d;
```

to your `body .circle.wpb_single_image img, body .circle.wpb_single_image a::before` class

So in terms of your question it was actually the other way around the image was square and the background was a circle it just was not clipping the image.

Comment: Would this class be in my style.css file as I can't see it?

Comment: Inspect the element in your browser and it should tell you where the file and line number is. On my phone now so can't look myself

Comment: style.css line 3587 same class where the border radius has been set

Comment: Thanks Quince, That's fixed it. First time I've used this site - fantastic response!

Comment: Well welcome to SO and glad i could help, if this answer has solved your issue you can mark it as the answer

Answer (score 0):

Try setting `border-radius:50%` instead of `border-radius:1000px`